# matlab 2014b libxerces-c.so.27: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: matlab

I have just installed matlab 2014b but when i tried to run it, I am getting this problem

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64/need_softwareopengl: error while loading shared libraries: libxerces-c.so.27: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: error while loading shared libraries: libxerces-c.so.27: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried to find it on the internet but most of them are 28 and 3.1. All the 27 i found seem to have broken link so how can I solve it ? I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Do you have `libxerces-c3.1` installed ?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, no package for the supported Ubuntu versions contains `libxerces-c.so.27`

Therefore create a symbolic link

```
sudo apt-get install libxerces-c28
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libxerces-c.so.28 /usr/lib/libxerces-c.so.27
```

---

An other idea, [here](http://olex.openlogic.com/packages/xerces-c/2.7.0) you can download `xerces-c-2.7.0`, the archive contains `libxerces-c.so.27`

```
% find . -name '*.so.27'
./xerces-c-2.7.0/lib/libxerces-c.so.27
./xerces-c-2.7.0/lib/libxerces-depdom.so.27
```

Answer (score -1):

In some cases no other version would work in place of 2.7. Not 2.8 neither 3.4. I found the 2.7 version of this shared library coming as part of another software [here](http://genie.weizmann.ac.il/software/nucleo_pred_exe/ver2_64bit_nucleosome_prediction.tar.gz). It is in the folder lib of the zipped file. 
I mention this since the website in the second method of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640228/matlab-2014b-libxerces-c-so-27-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or/683520#683520) does not seem to be freely available and the first mentioned method does not work for me. I spent two days finding this, hopefully it would save some trouble for other people.

```
wget http://genie.weizmann.ac.il/software/nucleo_pred_exe/ver2_64bit_nucleosome_prediction.tar.gz
tar -xvzf ver2_64bit_nucleosome_prediction.tar.gz
cd lib
sudo ln -s libxerces-c.so.27 /usr/lib/libxerces-c.so.27
```

Comment: This is the same suggestion as the 2nd part of [A.B.'s answer](/a/683520) only with a different link and without clear instructions.

Comment: The website in that answer does not seem to be  a freely accessible one.

Comment: In that case please press the [edit] link under the other question and suggest a different link as a change to it.